# Html.BeginRouteForm doesn't generate URL for named route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am attempting to use Html.BeginRouteForm to generate the action for a form in my ASP.NET MVC app.  The route I am targeting is:

```
//CREATE
routes.MapRoute("map-config-post", "projects/{projectId}/mapconfigs",
    new { controller = controllerName, action = "Create" },
    new { httpMethod = new RestfulHttpMethodConstraint("POST") });
```

Unit testing and following the route in the app is successful.  Now, I would like to create an HTML form with this route is it's URL:

```
@using (Html.BeginRouteForm("map-config-post", new { projectId = Model.Project.Id }))
{ 
    //form stuff
}
```

This results in an HTML form with a blank action attribute.  Googling around, it seems like this is supposed to work.  This is a "New" view, so the current (i.e., postback) route is

```
projects/1/mapconfigs/new
```

And I want it to post to

```
projects/1/mapconfigs
```

which is what the form action should be.

I can manually make this all happen if I don't use the helpers, but then I lose the nice auto-validation stuff on the client-side.

So, any ideas of what I am doing wrong?  Hopefully it's clear what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the problem comes from your custom `RestfulHttpMethodConstraint` constraint. Using the [default one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.httpmethodconstraint.aspx) works perfectly fine:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "map-config-post",
    "projects/{projectId}/mapconfigs",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Create" },
    new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("POST") }
);
```

and then:

```
@using (Html.BeginRouteForm("map-config-post", new { projectId = Model.Project.Id }))
{ 
}
```

generates:

```
<form action="/projects/123/mapconfigs" method="post">

</form>
```

Comment: Yup, but now it doesn't route to the Delete action if I post a form to that with the X-HTTP-Method-Override set to DELETE, which is what my custom constraint does.  So, I had to add the 'httpMethod' attribute into my RouteValueDictionary in BeginRouteForm to make it work. Thanks for putting me on the right track!