# How to change the way the Url is formatted on a submit

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-web-api

I have a search box in a Razor template:

```
    @{
        using (Html.BeginForm("Detail", "Book", FormMethod.Get))
        {
        @Html.TextBox("Id")
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        }
    }
```

When I submit a search it goes to a url like:

> ~/Book/Detail?Id=1234

However I want it to format the url like so, just because I think it looks cleaner:

> ~/Book/Detail/1234

Which works perfectly fine because the controller method signature looks like this:

```
    // GET: /Book/Detail/id
    public ActionResult Detail(string id)
```

**Model with TextBoxFor**

I've tried a `Html.TextBoxFor`:

```
    @model WebApplication.Models.SearchModel
    @{
        using (Html.BeginForm("Detail", "Book", FormMethod.Get))
        {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Id)
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        }
    }
```

Same result.

Comment: Could you please tell me, what is the purpose of generating this url? Are you want to pass those value or want to goto that route?

Comment: @PandiyanCool Both urls work the same and invoke the controller action `Detail`. I just prefer the look of the second one.

Comment: Oh okay:) do you want to implement the cleaner one?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to take a look at the @Html.BeginRouteForm method, like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810150/html-beginrouteform-doesnt-generate-url-for-named-route) question.

Comment: Thanks, I'm giving it a go, but it's got a load of overloads and not much help on MSDN.

Comment: meh... isn't really an option on second look. Sorry about that. Trouble is that for the 'route-like' syntax, the id needs to be passed into the BeginForm method. See the question and answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997629/how-to-get-razor-form-to-use-route

Comment: No problem, thanks for the help, I've found a [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18105353/360211)

Answer (score 1):

You use a `GET` request. This means that all parameters will appear in the url box.
I can't check now, but I suppose you could use these options:

1. The IIS url rewrite - http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite
2. Url rewrite through a web.config - http://www.hanselman.com/blog/RedirectingASPNETLegacyURLsToExtensionlessWithTheIISRewriteModule.aspx

And a batch of stupid methods:

1. You can change your request to `POST` and then modificate the Url by the JS - [Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)
2. You can redirect the request

Also, did you try to add a personal routing for the search url?

Comment: OK, well I'll bare those in mind, but I'm sure there is a simple way.

Comment: As for the personal routing - no I didn't try that, I don't know how or why?

Comment: How: in the `Global.asax` in the method `RegisterRoutes`. Why: I suppose that you shouldn't do this, because your Controller/Action/Parameter are same as default routing. I just didn't notice it at first time.

Comment: Yeah both urls work, so the mapping is there, I think now that it boils down to the html `<input>` submit will always put parameters at end of url after a `?`. So maybe the other ideas you put forward are nessasary.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I found a simple solution, see [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18105353/360211).

Answer (score 0):

Try using a model for the form submit and use @Html.TextBoxFor.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help. Maybe I'm doing it wrong, see edit to question.

Comment: try using  FormMethod.Post instead of Get

Comment: No, that won't help, that will not put anything in the url.

Comment: That's just it, there is no Post method. Only Get.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to add a new search action then redirect to the detail. This is nice because I can choose to do more when searching, such as returning a different view if the query has multiple matches.

```
    //
    // GET: /Book/Search?query=
    public ActionResult Search(string query)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Detail", new { id = query });
    }

    //
    // GET: /Book/Detail/id
    public ActionResult Detail(string id)
```

Razor:

```
@{
    using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Book", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        @Html.TextBox("query")
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    }
}
```